# Using rake db:migrate to create tables in database in mysql. Command appears successful, but databases have no tables

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, database, ubuntu

I've been tasked with working on a Ruby on Rails web application and have been given a laptop to work on it. I've managed to grab the source code and get the website up and running on the laptop, however, I can't seem to get rails to communicate *fully* with mysql.

The issue is that when I try to setup the database using rake commands all appears well until I go and check on the database. I can see that the databases from the database.yml file are created, but the migrated tables are not, even though during the migrate command they appear to be.

I've tried several times recreating the database and re-running the commands, and have even recreated the project, but still have not been able to get the tables to generate. If any other information is needed let me know!

Laptop is running Ubuntu(16.04 LTS)

A full list of used Gems:

- abstract (1.0.0)
- actionmailer (3.1.3)
- actionpack (3.1.3)
- activemodel (3.1.12, 3.1.3)
- activerecord (3.1.3)
- activeresource (3.1.3)
- activesupport (3.1.12, 3.1.3)
- ansi (1.4.2, 1.3.0)
- arel (2.2.3, 2.2.1)
- Ascii85 (1.0.1)
- bcrypt (3.1.11)
- bcrypt-ruby (3.0.1)
- builder (3.0.4, 3.0.0)
- bundler (1.0.17)
- by_star (1.0.1)
- chronic (0.10.2, 0.6.4)
- coffee-rails (3.1.1)
- coffee-script (2.4.1, 2.2.0)
- coffee-script-source (1.10.0, 1.1.2)
- css3buttons (1.0.1, 0.9.5)
- daemon_controller (0.2.6)
- devise (2.0.0, 1.4.9)
- erubis (2.7.0)
- execjs (1.3.0, 1.2.9)
- fastthread (1.0.7)
- hike (1.2.3, 1.2.1)
- i18n (0.6.0, 0.5.0)
- jquery-rails (1.0.19, 1.0.16)
- json (1.6.5, 1.6.4)
- kaminari (0.12.4)
- libv8 (3.3.10.2 x86_64-linux)
- mail (2.3.3, 2.3.0)
- meta_search (1.1.1)
- mime-types (1.25.1, 1.17.2)
- minitest (1.6.0)
- multi_json (1.12.1, 1.0.4)
- **mysql (2.9.1, 2.8.1)**
- **mysql2 (0.3.17, 0.3.11, 0.3.7, 0.3.6, 0.2.11)**
- orm_adapter (0.0.7, 0.0.5)
- pdf-reader (0.10.1)
- polyamorous (0.5.0)
- polyglot (0.3.5, 0.3.3)
- prawn (0.12.0)
- rack (1.4.7, 1.3.10, 1.3.6)
- rack-cache (1.1, 1.0.3)
- rack-mount (0.8.3)
- rack-ssl (1.3.4, 1.3.2)
- rack-test (0.6.3, 0.6.1)
- **rails (3.1.3)**
- railties (3.1.3)
- **rake (0.9.2.2, 0.8.7)**
- rdoc (3.12.2, 3.12, 2.5.8)
- sass (3.1.10)
- sass-rails (3.1.4)
- sprockets (2.0.5, 2.0.3)
- **sqlite3 (1.3.4)**
- therubyracer (0.9.8)
- thor (0.14.6)
- tilt (1.4.1, 1.3.3)
- treetop (1.4.15, 1.4.10)
- ttfunk (1.0.3)
- turn (0.8.3)
- tzinfo (0.3.51, 0.3.31)
- uglifier (1.0.4)
- warden (1.2.6, 1.0.6)
- wicked_pdf (0.7.2)

Comment: Can you please remove the sqlite gem from the gemfile. Bundle install and create a new database and then do the migrations?

Comment: sure i'll give it a shot!

Comment: yes, your commands should be `bundle install` -> `rake db:create` -> `rake db:migrate`

Comment: After removing Sqlite from the gemfile and try to do a rake db:reset command I'm getting a message stating to install sqlite3 adapter.

Comment: Are you sure you are checking tables for the right environment? `rake db:create` only creates the development database.

Comment: Apologies as I think I might be misunderstanding. I have two separate databases in the database.yml file that use mysql2 as its adapter; The user db and the production db. These are the two databases i'm trying to have tables generated for. I check for the tables using mysql on the command line and look into the databases from there. When I ran the db:create command the first time it created both those databases from the yml file.

Comment: Can you show us your `database.yml` and commands you are using for checking that tables exists?

Comment: add your database.yml to your original post and remove the host/password/username. By the way, you mentioned user db, it should be development, unless you are working from another environment called `user`, that db would never be created. Then you should remove sqlite3 from your Gemfile, under `development` replace with mysql2. Let us know when you've done that.

Comment: Tasking a developer who has never worked on RoR to work on a legacy app is a recipe for disaster. Make sure you guard your bases by being very upfront about your skill level and padding any time estimates with the time it takes to learn.